# Detect available time periods in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I work with varying datasets (panel data) and need to detect programmatically if I have daily, monthly, quarterly or only yearly data available. All the datasets have a date column with datetime format (e.g. yearly data only has year-end dates 31-12-2017, 31-12-2018 etc.; daily data might look like 02-02-2018, 03-05-2018, 09-11-2018 etc. with varying intervals).

For yearly data I would expect the date interval to be at 1 year, for quarterly data 3 months, for monthly data 1 month and daily data should have at least 2 dates within a month.

Is there a way with Pandas to detect what kind of date intervals I have available in the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

To check whether your DataFrame contains e.g. daily data (according to
your criterion), you can take the following approach:

As a source DataFrame I took:

```
            Value
Date             
2019-01-10     20
2019-01-15     12
2019-01-22     10
2019-02-08     11
2019-02-22     13
2019-03-11     17
2019-03-24     22
2019-05-07     14
```

*Date* is the index and it is of *datetime* type.

So there are:

- **3** readings for January,
- **2** readings for February and March,
- **no** readings for April,
- **1** reading for May.

To see how many readings you have for each month, run *resample* by month
and then (for each month) *count*:

```
df.Value.resample('MS').count()
```

In the code above *MS* means *month start*.

For my data the result is:

```
Date
2019-01-01    3
2019-02-01    2
2019-03-01    2
2019-04-01    0
2019-05-01    1
Freq: MS, Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

And to perform a single check whether you have at least 2 readings
for each month, run:

```
df.Value.resample('MS').count().ge(2).all()
```

For my data the result is *False*, due to no data in April and only 1 reading
in May.

For other periods take similar approach, resampling by different frequency
and criteria concerning how many readings you want in each period.

Comment: Great suggestion and explanation. Thank you, will give it a try!

Comment: one issue I just experienced: if all date entries are on the same day (i.e. end of month) I get the same result and no indication whether I actually have daily values or just a cumulation of values at the end of the month. Do you have an idea how to account for that? Thanks!

Comment: My try on the issue - exclude month end entries and count again: 

```month_end = df['Date'].dt.is_month_end  
df_count = df[-month_end] # inverted series to exclude month end entries  
df_count.Value.resample('MS').count()```